# 'QgsLayerTreeLayer' is not defined when running from python plugin but not when run in the console in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

When I run the following in a plugin I get

> name 'QgsLayerTreeLayer' is not defined

```
print('Loading raster layer...')
#QgsProject.instance().removeMapLayer(tLayer)
print("%s called %s" % (filePath, fname))
tLayer = QgsRasterLayer(filePath, fname, 'gdal')
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(tLayer, False)
layerTree = iface.layerTreeCanvasBridge().rootGroup()
layerTree.insertChildNode(-1, QgsLayerTreeLayer(tLayer))
```

However in python console it works

```
filePath=r'c:\resources\landcover.img'
tLayer = QgsRasterLayer(filePath, 'imagery', 'gdal')
layerTree.insertChildNode(-1, QgsLayerTreeLayer(tLayer))
```

Note: When I try the plugin without
layerTree = iface.layerTreeCanvasBridge().rootGroup()
I get

> name 'layerTree' is not defined

The plugin imports

```
from qgis.core import QgsApplication, QgsVectorLayer, QgsRasterLayer, QgsProject 
from qgis.utils import iface
```

Should I import something else? This is based on https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html

Purpose is to get the raster to load under all layers and also to stay on the bottom if other vectors are loaded after it.

Comment: Have you tried just adding the `QgsLayerTreeLayer` class to your import statement?

Comment: No I didn't but that worked...please post as the answer to accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import the `QgsLayerTreeLayer` class. Just add it to your import statement:

```
from qgis.core import QgsLayerTreeLayer
```